# What identity does git push use when run by a post-receive hook?

Tags: python, git, bash, github, git-post-receive

I have git on a development machine (`git1`, below).

I push changes to a git server (`mygitserv`, below).

That git server (`mygitserv`) uses a post-receive hook (`~/myrepo/.git/hooks/post-receive`) to forward changes on to Github (`github`, below).

```
git1 
    >==<git push>==> 
                     mygitserv 
                               >==<post-receive runs git push>==> 
                                                                  github

[myuser@gitserv:~] cat ~/myrepo/.git/hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
read oldrev newrev ref
echo "$oldrev"
echo "$newrev"
echo "$ref"
git push origin "$ref"
```

Here's the output I get on `git1` when I push to `mygitserv`:

```
remote: 9679d6ced07eafbbbd8595b1b4af887f2d8f3f52
remote: 1cee4034f0afcc3fd3babaa2cbcdd4aa6e0e3078
remote: refs/heads/mybranch
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
remote: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
To ssh://vagrant@localhost:19999/~/myrepo
   9679d6c..1cee403  mybranch -> mybranch
```

Simple, right?

Except that I get the dreaded `Permission denied (publickey)` from `gitserv` when I push a branch from my `git1` development machine.

Anyway, I'm suspicious that my agent-forwarding is messing this up, somehow.

```
[myuser@gitserv:~]$ git remote -v 
origin  git@github.com:v6/myrepo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:v6/myrepo.git (push)
```

That's why I'm asking about how git users work.

I can post the equivalent of the above code in Python 2.6 and Python 3.5, both of which I have already tried.

Which identity will a `post-receive` like the one on `gitserv` use to run its own `git push`?

Comment: // , Would using Pygit2 help with this, perhaps?

Comment: If you are using agent forwarding you need to forward your current credentials and apply them for the `git` user at `github.com`.

Comment: // , Let's say, theoretically, that I have added the public keys to Github. Let's also say that I did this for literally every identity in play, local or forwarded. It wouldn't matter, then, whether I forwarded the current SSH credentials or not, right? The question is just whether hooks, like `post-receive`, can be expected to use a different set of credentials than the host that the `post-receive` hook is stored on.

Comment: Try this guide: https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/